# What is the meaning of next-head-count in the header of NextJS SSR pages?

Tags: next.js

### QQ:

What is the meaning of the `next-head-count` meta tag sometimes included in the header of pages served on a NextJs server/app?

### Background

We have a next.js 9.0.3 server that behaves differently when built (build) and started (start) in AWS vs when built and started on a MacBook. (I think the root of it so far is that on AWS there is client-side render call when the page is presented, and on the Mac there is no client-side render called.)  That's not really what my question is about though.

I'm in the process of trying to understand the differences and while doing the  forensics I notice that /mypage.js HTML file initially served by the two platforms are different. The easiest difference to characterize here is that one platform serves a header with a next-head-count meta tag and the other does not:

```
<meta name="next-head-count" content="4"/>
```

So I ask my basic question above.

Answer (score 1):

```
<meta name="next-head-count" content="4" />
```

It is auto-injected and used internally by NextJS.

The `content=` attribute is equal to the number of elements that NextJS added within the `<head>` of your webpage.